# Non-empty interior of the convex hull of $f(a),f(b),f(c)$

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $a,b,c$ be three points in the plane which are not collinear. Let $f\colon \mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}^2$ be a continuous injective function. Show that the interior of
$$
f^{-1}\left[\mathrm{conv}\{f(a),f(b),f(c)\}\right]
$$
is non-empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be wrong. $f(x, y) = (x, x^2 + y)$ is injective and maps the non-collinear points
$$
  a = (-1, -1), \quad b = (0, 0), \quad c = (1, -1)
$$
to the (collinear) points
$$
 f(a) = (-1, 0), \quad f(b) = (0, 0), \quad f(c) = (1, 0) \, .
$$
$\mathrm{conv}\{f(a),f(b),f(c)\}$ is the line segment from $(-1, 0)$ to $(1, 0)$
and 
$$
  f^{-1}\left[\mathrm{conv}\{f(a),f(b),f(c)\}\right] = \{ (u, -u^2) \mid -1 \le u \le 1 \}
$$
which has empty interior.

---

If you assume that $f(a), f(b), f(c)$ are not collinear (instead of $a, b, c$)
then the statement becomes true.

A continuous *injective* function from $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is
an [open map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps), so $f$
maps an open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ to an open neighborhood $V$ of $f(a)$.

$\mathrm{conv}\{f(a),f(b),f(c)\}$ is a non-degenerate triangle. The intersection
of $V$ with the interior of this triangle is an open set $W$.
Then $f^{-1}(W)$ is an open set contained in 
$f^{-1}\left[\mathrm{conv}\{f(a),f(b),f(c)\}\right] \,$.

Comment: Oh, that is a bad surprise. Anyway I thank you because you spotted a mistake in my proof: the correct question had to be "let $a,b,c$ arbitrary points in the plane such that $f(a),f(b),f(c)$ are not collinear, then [...]", well! :)

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti: see updated answer ...

Comment: That was what I had in mind, exactly. In the light of your counterexample, I'd need the following condition on the function $f$: if $L$ is a straight line that $f[L]$ is another straight line [in practice, $f$ preserves the dimension of the affine hull of its argument]. Do such functions have a particular name?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti: I don't know.